# update table operation on Postgres database through xml file

Tags: java, xml, postgresql

I am getting error while updating the content in a table using Postgres database through mapping xml file & service class created in java.

Table structure, service class method, mapping xml file & test code are as follows

table :

```
CREATE TABLE "Itinerary"
(
  "ItineraryID" serial NOT NULL,
   "CustomerID" character varying(10) NOT NULL,
   "PropertyCode" character varying(10) NOT NULL,
   "ResvID" integer,
   "ProfileID" integer NOT NULL,
   "Summary" character varying(140),
   "Description" text,
   "CreatedBy" character varying(50),
   "CreatedOn" timestamp without time zone,
   "UpdatedBy" character varying(50),
    "UpdatedOn" timestamp without time zone,
    CONSTRAINT pk_itinerary PRIMARY KEY ("ItineraryID")
 )
```

mapping xml file: update operation

```
   <update id="updateSelective" parameterClass="com.ginfo.data.itinerary.ItineraryData">
    UPDATE "Itinerary" it
    <dynamic prepend="SET">
        <isNotNull prepend="," property="customerID">
            "CustomerID" = #customerID:VARCHAR#
        </isNotNull>
        <isNotNull prepend="," property="propertyCode">
            "PropertyCode" = #propertyCode:VARCHAR#
        </isNotNull>
        <isNotNull prepend="," property="resvID">
            "ResvID" = #resvID:INTEGER#
        </isNotNull>
        <isNotNull prepend="," property="profileID">
            "ProfileID" = #profileID:INTEGER#
        </isNotNull>
        <isNotNull prepend="," property="summary">
            "Summary" = #summary:VARCHAR#
        </isNotNull>
        <isNotNull prepend="," property="description">
            "Description" = #description:VARCHAR#
        </isNotNull>
        <isNotNull prepend="," property="updatedBy">
            "UpdatedBy" = "#updatedBy:VARCHAR#
        </isNotNull>
        <isNotNull prepend="," property="updatedOn">
            "UpdatedOn" = now()
        </isNotNull>
    </dynamic> 
    <include refid="Itinerary.where_PrimaryKey_Clause" />
</update>
```

Service class :

```
 public ItineraryData save( ItineraryData itinerary ) throws Exception
   {
      Integer itineraryID = null;
      if( itinerary != null )
       {
         try {
            itineraryID = itinerary.getItineraryID();
            if(itineraryID == null) {
                itineraryID = itineraryDAO.insert(itinerary);
                itinerary.setItineraryID(itineraryID);
            }
            else{
                itineraryDAO.updateSelective(itinerary);
            }
       }    
   }
```

Test Code:

```
        ItineraryData tinerary = new ItineraryData();
        itinerary.setItineraryID(23);
        itinerary.setCustomerID("0064152669");
        itinerary.setPropertyCode("BHS");
        itinerary.setResvID(9748);
        itinerary.setProfileID(4618);
        itinerary.setSummary("Schedule Preparation");
        itinerary.setDescription("Schedule Preparation Description");
        itinerary.setUpdatedBy(TESTUSER);
        ItineraryData itinerary2 = itineraryService.save(itinerary2);
        assertTrue("Itinerary  is saved", itinerary2!= null && itinerary2.getItineraryID() != null);
```

when I run the test code I am getting the following stack trace

```
Caused by: com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:   
--- The error occurred in resources/iBatis/BaseSqlMap.xml.  
--- The error occurred while executing update.  
--- Check the    UPDATE "Itinerary" it   SET         "CustomerID" = ?        ,     "PropertyCode" = ?        ,     "ResvID" = ?        ,     "ProfileID" = ?        ,     "Summary" = ?        ,     "Description" = ?        ,     "UpdatedBy" = "?                  WHERE         it."ItineraryID"=?           .  
--- Check the SQL Statement (preparation failed).  
--- Cause: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeUpdate(MappedStatement.java:110)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.update(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:457)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.update(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:90)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate$9.doInSqlMapClient(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:380)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate$9.doInSqlMapClient(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:200)
    ... 44 more
```

How to make it work?

Comment: There is an extra quotation mark in `"UpdatedBy" = "#updatedBy:VARCHAR#`

Comment: Thank you very much.  This solution resolved my issue.